# Ngrx complex state reducer

Tags: ngrx

I struggle finding the right way to mutate my state in an ngrx application as the state is rather complex and depending on many factors. This Question is not about doing one piece of code correct but more about how to design such a software in general, what are doe's and don'ts when finding some hacky solutions and workarounds.

The app 'evolved' by time and i wan't to share this process in an abstracted way to make my point clear:

**Stage 1**

State contains Entities. Those represent nodes in a tree and are linked by ids. Modifying or adding an entity requires a check about the type of nodes the new/modified ones should be connected with. Also it might be that upon modifying a node, other nodes had to be updated.

The solution was: create functions that do the job. Call them right in the reducer so everything is always up to date and synchronus when used (there are services that might modify state).

**Stage 2**

A configuration is added to the state having an impact on the way the automatically modifyed nodes are modifyed/created. This configuration is saved in it's own state right under the root state.

The solution:

1) Modify the actions to also take the required data from the configuration.

2) Modify the places where the actions are created/dispatched (add some ugly

```
this.state.select(fromRoot.getX)
.first()
.(subscribe(element => {this.state.dispatch(new Action({...old_payload, newPayload: element}))})
```

wrapper around the dispatch-calls)

3) modify the functions doing the node-modification and

4) adding the argument-passing to the function calls inside the reducer

**Stage 3**

Now i'am asked to again add another configuration to the process, also retrived by the backend and also saved in another state right under the root state

State now looks like:

```
root
|__nodes
|__config_1
|__config_2
```

i was just about to repeat the steps as in stage 2 but the actions get really ig with all the data passed in and functions have to carry around a lot of data. This seems to be wrong, when i actually dispatch the action on the state containing all the needed info.

How can i handle this correct?

**Some ideasi already had:**

use Effects: they are able to get everything from state they need and can create everything - so i only need to dispatch an action with only the actions payload, the effect then can grab everything from the state it needs. I don't like this idea because it triggers asynchronus tasks to modify the state and add not-state-changing actions.

use a service: with a service holding state it would be much like with effects but without using actions to just create asynchronus calls which then dispatch the actions that relly change state.

do all the stuffi n the component: at the moment the components are kept pretty simple when it comes to changing state as i prefer the idea that actions carry as little data as possible, since reducers can access the state to get theyr data - but this is where the problem occus, this time i can't get hands on the data i need.